# How Change Materials using Facesets in blender?

Tags: modeling, sculpting, remesh

Im trying to use blender with Quadremesher addon and guide topology flow using either Normal splitting or materials but for that i need to be able to add different materials or made facesets boundaries to defy normal splittings , i don't want to switch into edit mode and apply materials one by one since it takes too much , is there any way to convert face sets into different materials automatically or use them as smoothing groups ?

A quick update ,  materials do well (better than normal splitting with quad remesher ) actually better than normal splitting ...